# Searching a range of dates in a Microsoft Access 2013 form query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to search my database using a form where a user can enter a start date and an end date and return just those results. I have been trying everything these forums have said, but the results I am getting are everything EXCEPT the range I want. All that data is omitted.

I tried switching around the start/end date fields but that didn't work.

Here is what I have right now that returns the opposite results:

```
Like "*" & (([uut_result].[START_DATE_TIME]) Between [Forms]![TestFormResults]![StartDateTime] And [Forms]![TestFormResults]![EndDateTime]) & "*"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE (([uut_result].[START_DATE_TIME]) 
Between [Forms]![TestFormResults]![StartDateTime] 
And 
IIF([Forms]![TestFormResults]![EndDateTime] Is Null, Date(), [Forms]![TestFormResults]![EndDateTime])
```

What the `IIF()` does is it evaluates a condition, that would be the `EndDateTime = Null`. If is Null, aka `IsNull(EndDateTime) = True`, then it returns the *value if true* piece, which would be today's date. If `IsNull(EndDateTime) = False`, meaning there is a date in that control, it will return the *value if false*, which in this case is `[Forms]![TestFormResults]![EndDateTime]`.

The `*` is a [wildcard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx) in SQL. It is used to find variations of combinations of search criteria.

```
SELECT [Fields]
FROM [Table]
WHERE ((YourDateField) BETWEEN #[First date]# AND #[Second date]#)
```

This is assuming your field names are correctly referred to.
This `#` signs are for hard-coded dates. Using form control referencing does not require them (your syntax for the dates is fine.)

Comment: I have the wildcard since I used the same format for my other combo box fields where I want everything that contains perhaps an incomplete response. So for the dates If someone just enters the start date I want that to return everything from that date up to the present.

Comment: @user3783127 That's not what your question asked though.

Comment: Okay, yeah I left that part out by accident.

Comment: @johnnyappleseed try my update solution. Please reflect your actual question in the future.

Comment: Would you be able to explain briefly the change you made? It doesn't really make sense to me